# Advantages to uploading files to remote server

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, webserver

My php script allows users to upload images and stores them in a directory in the same server. Is there a security or performance advantage when transferring user uploaded files to a remote server on a different FTP account?

I imagine that it's more secure to store uploaded files on a server that isn't in the same directory with my php scripts and connected to my database. What are your thoughts? Advice on how to properly use a remote server is welcomed.

Note: I plan to use Codeigniter's [FTP Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/ftp.html) to handle all transfers and I'm saving image URLs to the remote directory in mysql.

Comment: when asking a security question, define what you are securing against.

Comment: malicious files being uploaded?

Comment: what is a malicious image? a photo of a bomb?

Comment: suppose its a php file with a jpg extension `bomb.php.jpg` obviously file validation will handle that but what if something else gets through.. Security against files uploaded by unknown users.

Comment: check file mime type, problem solved.

Comment: Yes. How about code that's inserted in image meta tags? I'm sure there are more security holes with uploads. I think the worst case scenario in a remote server is if someone deletes all the uploaded images. I'm paranoid about uploads...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no more secure than storing them on the same server as users can execute your PHP scripts as long as they know their locations. They can find a PHP script's location very easily without know it already (and without seeing images in the same directory).

You will see a decrease in performance (possibly very noticeably depending on how often you access emails) and won't see an increase in security.

If you don't want users to be able to execute your PHP files, you can change the read/execute capabilities of users in specified directorys (you could just put your PHP files outside of the folder with the photos if you want the users to have access to the images without having access to the PHP files)

If you are worried about users uploading files you don't want them to upload, you can limit the types of files they can upload by either saying "these file types are not allowed" or saying "only these file types are allowed" and checking with PHP when the file is uploaded.

Comment: Thanks, I'm more concerned about users uploading dangerous files in the same server. Maybe storing them on a remove server will reduce the risk. Also I can set up multiple servers, should one run out of space. I'm sure huge social websites use remote servers to store their immense collection of images.

Comment: You can limit (blacklist) the types of files or only allow (whitelist) certain types of files users can upload and then you won't have to worry about this at all.